# Scala Slick Tuple Database modeling

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I'm using mySQL db instance with slick.
I want to model the data retrieved from db into a model, but tuple limits the params to up to 22. I want to retrieve all 23 columns or more.
Is there any way I can define the * without using tuple?
Thanks.

```
def * = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, f, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w) <> (caseClass.tupled, caseClass.unapply)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've used Slick code generator, you'll see that it generates so called `HList`-s for tables that have more than 22 columns. They are not convenient to use IMHO.

I found an example in Slick tests that uses case classes mapping(nesting). You can look at my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sake92/7db67bfe400cc45775b86d58f1b6e7d8) for full example(also in code comments there are links to refer). I don't know if this is best practice, but it works.